# Liferay DDMStructure edited permissions not working as expected

Tags: java, permissions, liferay, liferay-6

I'm developing a portlet for Liferay 6.2, where I'm using DDMStructures. Of course I need to check for permissions. I noticed that when I create a structure - type of a document in Documents and Media portlet and I set permissions to it's initial state. (Example: Guest can see the choosen document type) everything is just fine, my portlet knows about this permission and uses it. The problem is, when I change this permission to invisible for a guest, this setting doesn't make any change in my portlet. It still uses an initial permission value.

I'm trying to check permissions by two methods:
1. via PermissionChecker

```
pCh.hasPermission(
                   structure.getGroupId(), DDMStructure.class.getName(), structure.getStructureId(),
                   ActionKeys.VIEW)
```

2. via getStructures method from DDMStructureServiceUtil

```
DDMStructureServiceUtil.getStructures(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId());
```

the same with

```
DDMStructureServiceUtil.getStructures(themeDisplay.getScopeGroup().getPrimaryKey());
```

It's something wrong with my checking for permissions, or it's a bug?
Thank you.

added:

I made a new portlet with simple code to find out if this issue is not cause by any other method in my original portlet. Here is the code which calls the getStructures method. Result is wtill the same. *(see comments for issue example)*

```
public class NewPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

    @Override
    public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest,
            RenderResponse renderResponse) {

        List allwithViewPerms = new ArrayList();

        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) renderRequest
                .getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

        try {
            allwithViewPerms = DDMStructureServiceUtil.getStructures(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId());
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (DDMStructure ddmStructure : allwithViewPerms) {
            System.out.println(ddmStructure.getNameCurrentValue());
        }
        System.out.println(allwithViewPerms.size());

        try {
            super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
        } catch (IOException | PortletException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

the same with getPrimaryKey() from scopeGroup.

Comment: Check in `control pane > Roles > Guest > Edit Permission` that Guest role not have the permission to see all DDMStructures. In this case try to remove it.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Guest doesn't see all structures, if I choose the initial permission not viewable by guest he can not see it, however when I edit it and give guest view permission, this doesn't make any change in permission checker or getStructures result. I'm pretty sure it's a bug. Will edit my original post with more info.

Comment: That method (getStructures) return all the structures for that group, has nothing to do with permission.

Comment: Returns all the structures in the group that the user has permission to view. From documentation, but user doesn't have permission to view that structures. However I got this issue with the permission checker too.

Comment: Try to use the `DDMStructureLocalServiceUtil` and not the `DDMStructureServiceUtil`. This second is for remote service.

Comment: returns all structures. I wonder why the initial setting is working and edited not. Because with the initial setting of permissions everything is just fine... That's weird isn't it.